# Wagon R burns engine oil

Tags: oil, suzuki

Suzuki Wagon R 2008 with 162000 on the odometer has started burning engine oil. What are the possible reasons & what are the repairs & costs?

Answer (score 1):

worn valves and valve guides

worn bores, weak / worn rings

Solutions:

head rebuild,

engine rebuild

Costs dependant on location :

labour can be expensive, parts relatively cheap or

labour cheap and parts expensive or non-existant...